# On the way to homology cross product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex, triangulation

Let X and Y be topological spaces and let $\sigma_m : \Delta^m \rightarrow X$ and $\sigma_n: \Delta^n \rightarrow Y$ be continuous maps from the standard simplices of dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively into X and Y (i.e., two singular simplices of X and Y). We have the product map
$$\sigma_m \times \sigma_n: \Delta^m \times \Delta^n \rightarrow X \times Y;$$ I want to write (?) this product map as a sum of $\binom{m+n}{m}$ singular $(m+n)$-simplices. I want to use the fact that $\Delta^m \times \Delta^n$ can be triangulated into $\binom{m+n}{m}$ simplices of dimension $m+n$. I don't know how to write the product map on each simplex. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe it is simply defined as the restriction of the product map to the $(m+n)$-simplex of the triangulation?

Comment: Yes that is how you would write it: the inclusion of the simplex into $\Delta^m \times \Delta^n$ followed by the product of the two continuous maps.

Answer (score 1):

There is an explicit map defined in a paper [1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02564371) by Eilenberg and Moore. You essentially sum over all possible factor-wise order-preserving inclusions $\Delta^{n+m}\to \Delta^{n}\times \Delta^m$, including signs, and then push forward by $\sigma$ and $\tau$. A good discussion of this can be found in Haynes Miller's lectures notes[2](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/papers/lectures-905-906.pdf).